# MikTeX package manager unable to download any packages

Tags: packages, miktex

I used to be able to download packages but recently I have been unable to do so for quite sometime now.  It gives the message:

```
get proxy host by name failed in tcp_connect()
```

I don't remember doing anything different except that I have moved from another location and I am using another broadband connect, but I am not sure if it is related to this problem.

Comment: Is your access to the Internet at the new location generally OK -- apart from the MikTeX update issue? Is your computer now behind a firewall that permits some connections but not others? Please provide more details about your current computing setup.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You might have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) if you wish to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I tried various things, nothing works. I have uninstalled Miktex, then reinstalled again. It worked for a little while, then it again became unable to install any packages. Now I removed the program again, but this time I cannot even install Miktex. It says Event: appcrash.

Comment: Some mirrors are down. I think I've been using the Polish one and switched to the Austrian one and that worked.