# MiKTeX: connect failed in tcp_connect

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

I already read these threads: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128121/cannot-install-mh-package-with-miktex), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107526/media9-sty-not-found), [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53107/package-repository-down-how-to-relocate) and [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111125/latex-packages-automatic-versus-manual-installation-and-related-issues) which address the connection error `connect failed in tcp_connect()`. I found out that the address I can't connect to is 178.77.68.21 but there is nothing `ftp://178.77.68.21` and `http://178.77.68.21`. It would even be helpful if someone could validate that this process works for him *right now*. Which file do I need to change to force a repository change to something like [CTAN](ftp://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/).

This is a clean fresh installation (but reinstalling seems to have helped [this guy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136740/miktex-package-manager-unable-to-download-any-packages) at least temporarily). Also I do not have any other problems with my internet connection on any port.

I have no firewall. And get the following:

[image: Installation dialog comes up]

[image: Installation failed]

[image: Synchronize failed]

[image: Repo change failed]

## Update1

Obviously this issue can't be generalized some of us suffer sometimes from it and have to deal with it while generating specific solutions. When I solved this problem I will post (in detail) what was the cause and the fix to it.

## Update2

The solution is that MikTex won't use the systems default proxy settings. It always assumes that there is no proxy. On Windows use the console `cmd.exe` and type `ipconfig /all` and `proxycfg -u`(or `netsh winhttp import proxy ie`) to find all necessary information about your NICs. The line `Proxyserver` from proxycfg command will tell you what to enter here:
[image]

Yes, I am behind a proxy on this machine and didn't take this into account...

Comment: This happens to me when a MiKTeX mirror is not online. Try changing the repo to another manually. Or you can't do that either?

Comment: @marczellm Could you explain how to do it manually. So which file will I have to edit. Until now I only used the GUI which is not working at the moment as you can see in the 4th image. Could you please also link in your answer to an up-to-date mirror list.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that cannot retraced by other users, because it was either temporary or caused by a not TeX related connection problem.

Comment: Please reopen this question. It is very relevant to all Miktex users, who struggle with it again and again. Let's try to solve it together!

Comment: I had this problem too, but the solution with the proxy didn't work for me, since I was not using a proxy. I solved the problem by uninstalling MiKTeX and then installing it again with the NET installer (https://miktex.org/download -> All downloads). I installed it with all packages. More a workaround than a solution but for me it works.

Comment: I have the same problem.   Where do I ask the question?  It is clearly a failure of MikTex, it is not a failure of windows or the internet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything works fine here. I just made an update and installed new packages.

Some more information:

[178.77.68.21 - Reverse IP Lookup on DomainTools](http://reverseip.domaintools.com/search/?q=178.77.68.21) shows you, that this IP is used amongst others for http://miktex.org/. The reason  is that in these cases, when you have package installation from a random or from the “nearest” repository selected, the page http://api.miktex.org/Repository.asmx is called. Maybe this was temporarily down or you have more serious connection issues from your region.

But this is not TeX related and also for your question is guilty what I wrote in [Cannot install MiKTeX 2.9 after a new Windows installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162343/162364):

> “Sorry, but this kind of questions is not answerable on a valuable level. The issue is in most cases not related to MiKTeX installer itself, not speaking of TeX in general”.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since the problem persists for me the problem is obviously on my side.
I totally agree that this is off topic in the context of *coding in tex* but to find information you need context or at least some kind of *anchor-keywords* pointing to a topic. As a user of an application you are only connected to the front-end/top layer such that the *anchor* for a problem will always be the applications name or its specific usage. Though I agree with you I don't know of any better place to put such issues.

Comment: @dkeck: All these questions like yours are only closed, not deleted, and hence can be found by other people facing this or a similar issue.

Comment: The problem is encountered by many users again and again. And IT IS related to Miktex. So it would be nice if people were less arrogant. After all this site is designed to help others with the problems.