# HTTP Error when trying to change repository

Tags: miktex, repositories

Today I wanted to install some new packages in the Package Manager. I got an error message saying:
"MiKTeX Problem Report
Message: HTTP Error
Data: HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"

I checked and found out, that the repository I used is indeed unavailable at the given adress. I then tried to change the repository. After selecting "Packages shall be installed from the Internet" and clicking "next", the same error message appears and the list of available repositories is not loaded. So basically, I cannot change the repository because the repository I used is not online, which is actually the most important reason for changing the repository.
Does anybody know a solution for this? I guess a workaround would be to change the adress of the repository manually, but for this, one would need to know where it is stored. I've added a screenshot-mashup to show the problem.
[image: screenshot-mashup]

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because I haven't tested it but... Searching my Windows Registry for the mirror I use, I found a key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/MiKTeX.org/MiKTex/2.9/MPM/RemoteRepository` that stores the address of the remote repository. With the usual caveats about being careful editing the registry you could either delete that key or change it to an accessible repository (the actual repository doesn't matter, since as long as it is accessible you can always change it through the GUI). Hope it helps!

Comment: Did you try to change the repository from the menu in the package manager itself?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes I did. I actually did that first, right when I was unable to install the new packages. There, it is the same issue: an error and then no list of available repositories is loaded. Only then, I tried it in the MiKTeX options and encountered the same problem.

Comment: @darthbith Thanks, I guess I will try that. Do you know where to find the adress of another repository? On miktex.org they are only listed by hosts, but not with their full adress...

Comment: @Janek Mine is `ftp://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/`

Comment: Hmmm, I changed the repository and the new repository is shown in the options. I still get the same error, though. Seems to be a more complicated problem after all. I guess I have to try to reinstall MiKTeX. I only hope it works. Right now, I'm only missing a few (very important) packages. If reinstalling fails, I'm without TeX completely...

Comment: Imho miktex gets the list of repositories from the main miktex server. So if a local repository is down this should affect it. Try to use mpm on the command line. Perhaps this works. Btw: You can download packages directly from CTAN and create a local repository. Get the two miktex-zz-files from /tm/packages and the packages you need and put them in some empty folder outside miktex.

Comment: I do not observe problems from here. Before you continue delete the DNS cache (on Command Prompt: `ipconfig /flush`) and try again … Look on [MiKTeX Package Repositories](http://miktex.org/pkg/repositories), whether the selected repositories are available and up to date … Perhaps just MiKTeX.org itself was unreachable, cf. my answer [MiKTeX: connect failed in tcp\_connect](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167713).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue that appears to be temporary and localized, and hence cannot be retraced by others.