# Spacing between lines + unable to install package

Tags: spacing, packages, miktex, installing, setspace

I need to increase the spacing between lines for my thesis.

It seems like "setspace" is what I have to use (`\usepackage{setspace}`) but i get...

```
The required file tex\latex\setspace\setspace.sty is missing...
Package will be installed from > Change > Installation source.
```

That's fine, problems start here:

- If I choose "should be installed from Internet", I need to specify connection settings, only option is "use a proxy server", but it will only tell me "connect failed in tcp_connect()".
- If I choose "should be installed from a directory", I fail to find the appropriate directory and only get the error "Not a local repository."

I tried to download from `https://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace` but am unable to find where to copy the files.

I tried MiKTeX-Package-Manager, found setspace, clicked "+", but get a MiKTeX-ProblemReport saying "No Data" and "get host by name failed in tcp_connect()"

As an alternative I have tried `\baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip`, but it won't increase spacing between lines in my bibliography (embedded with `\bibliography{bib}`).

Can you give me directions? Thank you!

**Edit**:

I used `\linespread{1.5}` and it seems to work.

It would still be interesting why I can't install any packages. My problem seems to be the same as described in [MiKTeX: connect failed in tcp_connect](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167562/miktex-connect-failed-in-tcp-connect). But I have no clue about proxies so I can't proceed.

Comment: To setup a local repository you need the files from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages. You need at least the files starting with miktex-zzdb, and the packages you want to install. Put them all in some empty folder outside miktex.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the server was temporaly not available. Now it is online ...

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. Looks like the package repository is temporarily offline. Don't know when it will work again.

[image: Message on Miktex.org]

Comment: As of this morning (UTC) this warning message is gone and at least for me update worked brilliantly a few minutes ago.